# dynamic baked hair rendering as completely limp

Tags: hair

I have a hair simulation that seems to bake properly, but renders as though gravity is as strong as the sun's surface -- limp and super long:

[image]

The hair is indeed rather long.  At first it's only the rendering that appears to be wrong, and I tried fiddling with the render Hair settings with no luck.  But then if I change the setting on B-spline (on or off), then the hair in the Viewport also appears limp!   So perhaps it's a hair setting.   What is going on here ([example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izxt29kv6lu1aq8/Hair%20render%20problem.blend?dl=0); blender-exchange broken again today)?

Comment: That's weird. It works fine until you bake the Dynamic Hair. Then it's broken in the render. If you turn the particle system (PS) off and on again in the viewport then it's also broken in the viewport. Delete the bake, toggle the PS off/on and it's fine again.

Comment: @Blunder -- it's driving Miss Daisy Crazy !!  Hmm I can successfully render without baking... go figure!

Comment: Yes, without baking it works. It breaks as soon as you bake it. But if you bake it to disk (either by ticking Cache > [X] External *-OR-* Cache > [X] Disk Cache) then it works, too! Looks like the memory cache has a bug? (Giving it a unique name doesn't help) -- I wonder why the hair cap is not shown in the final render. [X] Show Emitter is checked and it's enabled for render. Where is it?

Comment: @Blunder -- I assigned a clear glass to mesh surface, so that's expected.  I'll report a bug.   You're help/time appreciated!!!

Comment: Ah, that's the invisible trick! I had not checked the shader. Greetings to Miss Daisy ;-)

Comment: @Blunder -- I reported "https://developer.blender.org/T98599" and the word is: "marking as a known issue because hair particle system is end of life".  Just when we become an expert at sometime, it gets depricated, LOL.